# Documentation of stack not updating after being added to rosdistro/kinect.yaml

Tags: ros, documentation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**The problem:** I followed the guidelines in [Indexing Your ROS Repository for Documentation Generation](http://wiki.ros.org/rosdistro/Tutorials/Indexing%20Your%20ROS%20Repository%20for%20Documentation%20Generation)
and everything seemed to worked fine until the documentation page generation.

**The stack:** auction_mehtods_stack

**The steps undertaken:**

1. updated https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/kinetic/distribution.yaml with the new stack for indexing.
2. The pull request was accepted.
3. The indexer job finished and status reported ok.
4. However, the documentation page for the corresponding stack in wiki.ros.org did not correctly update to include the new distro documentation.

**The question:**
Did someone faced a similar problem, or have any suggestion on how to resolve this issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267627/documentation-of-stack-not-updating-after-being-added-to-rosdistro/kinect.yaml/) by [joaoquintas](https://answers.ros.org/users/3707/joaoquintas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2017-07-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know why, but apparently the Doc job didn't find any packages in the repository you submitted:

```
03:42:12 No packages found in source space: /tmp/catkin_workspace/src
03:42:12 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
03:42:12 ~~  traversing 0 packages in topological order:
03:42:12 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

If there are no packages, then there is no documentation to generate.

---

Edit: and I think I know why: *stacks* don't exist any more in ROS, and since Fuerte we've moved on to another build system (ie: [Catkin](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin)). All the packages in the repository you submitted ([joaoquintas/auction_methods_stack](https://github.com/joaoquintas/auction_methods_stack/tree/15189d01514cfaa06f7fda149a82693705754fae)) are rosbuild packages (ie: the old build system, which uses `manifest.xml` files).

The buildfarm uses Catkin for all Doc jobs, and Catkin doesn't support rosbuild packages in this way.

So when the Doc job crawls your repository, it finds 0 packages -> no documentation generated -> nothing updated on the wiki.

You'll have to migrate your packages to Catkin. See the [migration guide](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild) for how to do that. Be sure to check the [catkin howto documentation](http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/index.html) when something is unclear.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1